# Search bar for Django MultipleChoiceField form

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

First of all sorry if my question is very simple, but i am a beginner in Django. I have a MultipleChoiceField form, containing many cities of US. I just want to add a search bar sto i can type some letter of the city and filter my results instead of scrolling.I also have another form in the same logic but with multiselct including categories. This is my form:

```
from django import forms


class CityForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cities = kwargs.pop("City")
        super(CityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["City"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=cities, label='City name        ',
                                                widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'submit();'}))


class CategoryForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        categories = kwargs.pop("Category")
        super(CategoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["Category"] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=categories, label='Categories')
```

I don't want to use modelChoice as i am begginger and it seems very complex
This is my html template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
<p>Now select one or more categories you are interested in</p>
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form2.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Category">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any simple way to add a seach bar?

Comment: Check out [Select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: I am a little bit confused. i should install select2 in the way your link describes or like this link describes? https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Should i change my forms.py or just the html template?
I would be gratefull to you if you answer me this

Comment: The link is for a javascript library. Check out[this] (https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage) on how to use it. You will just include the relevant script in your html. However, you may need to add a class to your select input. The above link may help.